# Flex HBox with background color and rounded corner, wiered problem

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar, rounded-corners, hbox

I am facing a wiered problem in Flex. I Have a canvas with a HBox and Label. Please find the code below.

```
   <mx:VBox verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center"
        fontSize="12" fontWeight="normal" verticalGap="0">
        <mx:Label text="Cover" />
        <mx:Canvas width="120" styleName="pbcontainer">
            <mx:HBox id="pb" height="35" />
            <mx:Label id="dashboard_cover" fontWeight="normal" 
                      fontSize="20" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:VBox>


.pbcontainer {
    cornerRadius: 15;
    backgroundColor: #FFFFFF;
    borderStyle: solid;
    borderThickness: 2;
    borderColor: #000000;
}
```

I am trying to implement a `ProgressBar` here.
Now, the problem is if the `percentWidth` of `pb` is less than 5, the `haloBlue` color is spilling out which is not desired. Please find the image below. Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

[image]    [image]

Thanks,
Anji

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, instead of using an `HBox` with a background, try using a `ProgressBar` and set its progress instead of `percentWidth` of the `HBox`.

**Edit**: Oh well, based on the discussion in the comments, it seems the above solution is not feasible. Did you try setting the `cornerRadius` on the inner `HBox`? It is the one with the blue background isn't it?

Comment: @Shrikant Sharat Thanks for the idea, but my requirement here is to create a `ProgressBar` with rounded corners. When I replace the `HBox` with `ProgressBar` I see square corners which is not desired.

Comment: did you set `cornerRadius` to the `ProgressBar`?

Comment: There is no `cornerRadius` property for `ProgressBar`

Comment: @Shrikant Sharat Yup I have set the `cornerRadius` for the `HBox`. The problem is if the `percentWidth` of the `HBox` is less than say 5% [I found this to be 5% by some trial and error]I encounter this problem.. otherwise it works as expected.

Comment: well then, I'm all out of ideas. I don't have flex on my system to try out... I'll see if I can get some time to do it :)